# Access Each Character in a String in Swift 2

Tags: string, swift, swift2, xcode7

```
let amount = "73.45"
```

I want four different constants (strings, not characters) with each number in this string. Ideally:

```
let amount1 = amount[0] // 7
let amount2 = amount[1] // 3
let amount3 = amount[3] // 4
let amount4 = amount[4] // 5
```

I have searched and can't find anything that works, I either get the whole string or a character of the string. Any advice would be helpful--new to xcode and swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always get the characters using

```
let characters = amount.characters
```

to get strings instead of characters, you can:

```
let amount1 = String(characters[0])
```

to do it for all digits

```
let amounts = amount.characters.map {
   return String($0)
}
```

To filter out the separator, you can

```
let amounts = amount.characters.map {
    return String($0)
}.filter {
    $0 != "."
}
```

Note that if you have the input number localized, you should check `NSLocale` for the correct decimal separator or just remove all non-numeric characters. One way to do that is using:

```
let amounts = amount.characters.filter {
    $0 >= "0" && $0 <= "9"
}.map {
    String($0)
}
```

You can put your digits into separate variables then but I would advise against it:

```
let amount1 = amounts[0]
let amount2 = amounts[1]
let amount3 = amounts[2]
let amount4 = amounts[3]
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me a lot +1